# Where does NSKVOPendingNotificationCreate come from?

Tags: cocoa

I'm getting an object called after being deallocated and it is being called from NSKVOPendingNotificationCreate. What is it and what does it do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's an internal part of the KVO notification system in Foundation. What it does isn't particularly important, but what the crash is telling me is that an object's lifetime has been mismanaged.

You could run your application with the `NSZombieEnabled` environment variable set to `YES` and that would tell you which object was being messaged after deallocation.

Comment: The zombie was still observing another object. [otherObject addObserver:zombie forKeyPath:@"brains" context:apocalypse]

Comment: @joels I have been pulling my hair out over this one. Your comment saved me! (And I love your clever use of zombies as well.) Thanks mate!